# Map measurements

Tags: league-of-legends

Recently, the range of the `Gate` ability of `Twisted Fate` has been reduced from Global Range to 5500 units. The problem is, you can't possibly measure your range before activating the `Destiny` skill.

Do someone know about the different measure of the 5v5 map?

Of course I could learn play to play to know approximately where I can TP or not... but that is not efficient. If I could know it in advance.

It seems that mid-top to mid-mid is not possible. From my few games with this new configuration, it seems that the range **might** represents 1/3 of the map.

Comment: Hm. Has Pantheon's ult also been reduced to 5500? Does the range upgrade with level (like Nocturne)? It's not inconceivable that Riot might fix this in a future patch, as it seems like oversight more than anything.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Pantheon's ultimate has also been reduced to 5500. Range does not upgrade with level. I don't want to discuss balance of champions, but I feel I got ******. Com'on, you can't even see the radius without casting the first step of the Ultimate?!

Comment: Doesn't it show the range on mouse over the spell icon ?

Comment: @Dalshim I need to check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rough answer of what the distance 5500 represents :

> 5500 range is about from your Inhibitor to the outer mid turret.

EDIT : What's important here is :

- Range doesn't improve with skill level
- Range isn't big enough for lane swap, you first need to get closer before using ult.

Comment: Assuming you have a move speed of 400 units/second it takes you at least 13.75 seconds to move a distance of 5500 units. Having 400 ms would require you have a base of 330 (the highest base in the game shared by roughly three characters) and boots +2 and/or some masteries/runes etc. To make the walk in 10 seconds would require you have 550 ms which is not practical for most characters.

Comment: @Bravo840 Indeed I didn't think about quickly calculating it. But totally true. Had found this quote on another forum dealing the same problem, I'll edit to prevent misunderstanding. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7):

When mousing over the ability icon a white circle will appear on the minimap representing the abiliy's range. Check out [Patch Preview Video 1.0.0.122](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrSNXkBQ4K8#t=1m32s) at 1:32. It clearly shows the range of Twisted Fate's Ultimate on the minimap (5500 if you look closely at the tooltip) in the lower right corner. It looks like it is approximately 2/3 of the total map distance in height but roughly, maybe just less than, 1/2 the distance from Blue to Purple on the diagonal.